# How can I do a cdromupgrade if 12.10 does not have an alternate iso?

Tags: 12.10

Canonical dropped support to the alternate ISO's and they are not listed in the downloads page, how can I do a CD ROM upgrade now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correction:

Apparently you can't.  I've just burned a 12.10 DVD and booted off it to have a look, but it is not offering and upgrade option, only 'use all of the disk' 'install alongside' and 'something else'.  It seems they have indeed removed the CD upgrade option.

Even holding down <kbd>Space</kbd> to get to the utility menu does not yield an upgrade.

I think there were some problems with the CD upgrade in past versions but I thought it was one of the better ideas I've seen regarding upgrades.  Let's hope it comes back in future releases.

Comment: The desktop iso now does pretty much everything the alternate iso used to do - including preseeded installations!

Comment: So I can't upgrade using that :'( Can I at least use the packages in the iso to cut the download, if so how ?

Comment: You can mount the squash filesystem on the DVD to /mnt with the command 'sudo mount /media/Ubuntu\ 12.10\ i386/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt -t squashfs -o loop' however there' no .deb files on the squash filesystem.  I have no doubt you could do a manual upgrade if you knew what you were doing (I don't) but it seems like it's getting a bit hard.